# rebol --do and red --do

Tags: rebol, red

Why rebolview --do "print 1 + 2" doesn't show result in console ?

Why red --do "print 1 +2" generate an error

```
*** Error: cannot access argument file:
print 1 + 2
--== Red 0.6.3 ==--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here rebolview shows the result in the console

```
3
>> 
>> help system        
SYSTEM is an object of value: 
   version         tuple!    2.7.8.4.3 
   build           date!     6-Jan-2011/22:55:55-8:00 
   ..
```

but Red does not know the command **--do**. So it tries to run the file --do ..

You can see what Red is supporting at this time e.g. on Linux with

```
./red  -h
```